# Avoiding UAC in vista

Tags: c++, windows-vista, uac

im writing an application that downloads and installs addons for programs which needs to save the data to program files (for the programs in question). Now this works fine on xp and vista with uac disabled however it is failing on normal vista due to the virtual folders.

How would one get around this with out needing to request admin rights every time the app started?

P.s. Program is written in c++, vis 2005

Edit: File system virtual folders: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/MakingAppsUACAware.aspx

Comment: What exactly is triggering UAC? and um, excuse my ignorance, but what are virtual folders?

Comment: Why would the addons need to write to other folders in Program Files every time the app started? Wouldn't it only happen if you were installing an add-on? You may want to be a little clearer in what you are trying to do... getting around UAC seems like a symptom of a larger design problem.

Comment: Virtual folders are the place vista saves files instead of the normal folder. For example when saving to program files, vista will redirect that to a folder in the users document settings so to other users of the system, that file never existed.

Comment: Romandas, this is true however, the app has automatic updates for the addons and can cause the prompt to come up quite often thus the want to avoid it.

Comment: @Lodle - Right, but the point of UAC is to warn a user of exactly the behavior you're designing into the product. Programs writing to the install areas of other programs is a classic malware technique.

Comment: i know, but in this case its a feature of the program and i would prefer not to nag users about it

Comment: How would your application behave on Windows 2000 or Windows XP as a standard user? That will guide how you should behave on Windows Vista or Windows 7 as a standard user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around uac by making a windows service that does the work i need and only runs while the app is running.

Answer (score 9):

Only write to Program Files during installation.  After that, write to the user folders.

You can elevate the apps privileges later, but you'll just be delaying the prompt.  The whole point of UAC is to prevent random apps from writing to folders that require admin privileges.  (ok, not the whole point, but a large portion of it.)

You could create a service with admin privileges and send commands to it to move the downloaded files into the desired target directories, but this opens up a user's system to being abused by other apps if you don't design it very carefully.

[This article talks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163486.aspx) about getting apps to work nicely with UAC.  Also, [see this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.uac.aspx) here.

Comment: I cant, as i need to install addons for other programs in program files

Comment: Can you store the addons in another directory that does not need admin rights?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft recommended to me when I spoke to them to have to write a second application, which you manifest as requiring administrative privileges.  You use this application to deploy your file from a safe location (such as the users programdata directory) to the program files directory (Note that if your DLL isn't signed then this is a massive security hole as a virus/malicious user could manipulate the file before your function call).

Your non administrative app can call this application which will trigger UAC.  People who understand UAC won't care and happily will click your application.  Those who hate it will have switched it off.  The call to start the new process (which required admin privileges) will throw a win32 exception if the user cancels the UAC dialog so beware to catch that.

The problem in vista is that it tries to help you by virtualising your program files directory if you are not admin. By design there is NO way that you can write to the program files directory unless you're administrator.

Another option is to create all of your "updates" as MSI updates.  That way the windows installer will trigger UAC for you and you could provide a logo for your software etc.

Option 3 is to use clickonce deployment which will allow you to automatically update your program without UAC but you live in a sandbox on the users system which may not work with your application's current design.

Comment: Do services differ from normal apps in regards to uac? Maybe it would be a better way to make a service that does the updating.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm writing an application that downloads and installs addons for programs which needs to save the data to program files (for the programs in question). Now this works fine on xp and vista with uac disabled however it is failing on normal vista due to the virtual folders.

That's your problem. `Program Files` is not the correct location for addons. The **Program Files** folder is for applications. That folder is protected so that it cannot be modified by standard users (or malware running as a standard user).

Ancillary data that can be updated belongs in `ProgramData`. E.g.:

```
%ProgramData%\Contoso\Frobber\Addons
```

And then during installation you alter the permissions on your **ProgramData** folder to grant **Full Control** to **Everyone**:

```
procedure GrantAllUsersFullControlOfFileOrFolder(Path: string);
const
    SECURITY_NULL_SID_AUTHORITY:    TSIDIdentifierAuthority = (Value: (0,0,0,0,0,0));  //S-1-0  ntifs.h
    SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY:   TSIDIdentifierAuthority = (Value: (0,0,0,0,0,1));  //S-1-1
    SECURITY_LOCAL_SID_AUTHORITY:   TSIDIdentifierAuthority = (Value: (0,0,0,0,0,2));  //S-1-2
    SECURITY_CREATOR_SID_AUTHORITY: TSIDIdentifierAuthority = (Value: (0,0,0,0,0,3));  //S-1-3
    SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY:          TSIDIdentifierAuthority = (Value: (0,0,0,0,0,5));  //S-1-5

    //Relative identifiers (RIDs)
    SECURITY_NULL_RID  = 0;         //in authority S-1-0
    SECURITY_WORLD_RID = 0;         //in authority S-1-1
    SECURITY_LOCAL_RID = 0;         //in authority S-1-2
    SECURITY_CREATOR_OWNER_RID = 0; //in authority S-1-3
    SECURITY_CREATOR_GROUP_RID = 1; //in authority S-1-3

    SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID = $00000020; // 32 --> S-1-5-32
    DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS     = $00000220; //544 --> S-1-5-32-544
    DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_USERS      = $00000221; //545 --> S-1-5-32-545 A local group that represents all users in the domain.
var
    usersSID: PSID;
    sd: PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
    oldAcl, newAcl: PACL;
    dw: DWORD;
    ea: EXPLICIT_ACCESS;
begin
    //Create a well-known SID for the "Users" group (S-1-5-32-545)
    usersSid := StringToSid('S-1-5-32-545'); //well-known "Users" group
    try
        //Get the current DACL. Free SecurityDescriptor with LocalFree
        sd := nil;
        dw := GetNamedSecurityInfo(PChar(Path), SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nil, nil, @oldAcl, nil, {var}sd);
        if (dw <> ERROR_SUCCESS) then
            RaiseLastWin32Error;
        try
            // Initialize an EXPLICIT_ACCESS structure for the new ACE
            ZeroMemory(@ea, SizeOf(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
            ea.grfAccessPermissions  := GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE or GENERIC_EXECUTE {or GENERIC_ALL}; //Yes, it's not "really" full control
            ea.grfAccessMode         := GRANT_ACCESS;
            ea.grfInheritance        := SUB_CONTAINERS_AND_OBJECTS_INHERIT;
            ea.Trustee.TrusteeForm   := TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
            ea.Trustee.TrusteeType   := TRUSTEE_IS_GROUP; //TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP;
            ea.Trustee.ptstrName     := PChar(usersSID);

            // Create a new ACL that merges the new ACE into the existing ACL. Use LocalFree to free newAcl
            dw := SetEntriesInAcl(1, @ea, oldAcl, {var}newAcl); //use LocalFree to free newAcl
            if dw <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
                RaiseLastOSError(dw);
            try
                //Attach the new ACL as the object's new DACL
                dw := SetNamedSecurityInfo(PChar(Path), SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nil, nil, newAcl, nil);
                if (dw <> ERROR_SUCCESS) then
                    RaiseLastWin32Error;
            finally
                LocalFree(HLOCAL(newAcl));
            end;
        finally
            LocalFree(HLOCAL(sd));
        end;
    finally
        LocalFree(HLOCAL(usersSid));
    end;
end;
```

You could also grant everyone full control to your **Program Files** folder if you really don't want to put it in the correct [**ProgramData** folder.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-shell-setup-folderlocations-programdata)